# How does heapq.merge() work with infinite generators?

Tags: python, merge, heap, priority-queue, heapq

I want to understand how [`heapq.merge()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) works with infinite generators. Consider this example:

```
>>> from heapq import merge
>>> from itertools import count
>>> m = merge(count(0, 2), count(1, 2))
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print(next(m))
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The docs state that it does not pull the data into memory all at once. But how does it consume each of the infinite generators?

Comment: The inputs are assumed to be sorted, so it just has to check the first element of each and yield the lower one, kind of like merge sort.

Comment: BTW, are you asking "how is this possible" or "how is it implemented"?

Comment: `check the first element of each` - you can't do it with generators, can you? Yes, I'm interested in the implementation.

Comment: You can not "peek" the first element, but you can "pop" / yield it and remember it for later in case it is not the smallest.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "how does it consume each of the infinite generators"? Your question *already* consumes an infinite generator, so you seem to know how to do this. Are you asking how the algorithm to select the next item from all generators works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *very* simple implementation of such a function could look like the following. Note, though, that for the sake of simplicity this does not handle any special (and not-so-special) cases like empty or exhausted iterables.

```
def merge(*iterables):
    heap = [(next(it), i) for i, it in enumerate(iterables)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    while heap:
        val, i = heapq.heappop(heap)
        yield val
        heapq.heappush(heap, (next(iterables[i]), i))
```

It works like this:

- get the first element from each *sorted* iterable, together with that iterable's index in the list
- yield the next smallest element from that heap
- add the next element from the iterable with the same index as the one just yielded to the heap

The actual implementation is a bit more involved, but seems to work roughly along the same lines. You can get the location of your local source with `heapq.__file__`, which on my system is `/usr/lib/python3.6/heapq.py`, and check yourself.